# Categorization of PBE refinements into forward/backward looking?

Tags: game-theory

I have recently come across the term forward / backward looking refinement of a Perfect Bayesian Equilibrium. I am, however, unsure about the meaning of this term, and unable to find any information about this. Does anyone know the difference between the two? For instance, is a PBE refined with Intuitive Criterion a PBE with forward looking refinement (as the IC makes a statement about how beliefs should be influenced by off-equilibrium-path actions, and thus influences plays in further periods)?
If so, what would be an example for a backward looking refinement?

Answer (score 1):

The usual examples are [backward induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backward_induction) and [forward induction](http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~abranden/forward-01-04-07.pdf). Somewhat surprisingly, backward induction is forward looking and forward induction is backwards looking.

In backward induction you start at the end of the game- which lies in the future. So it is forward looking. Forward induction, which has many differen definition, uses reasoning based on a player having arrived at a node because another player in the past did something for some reason, so it looks backward.

I would not think too much about forward and backward looking behavior, it is often not that illuminating. As a matter of fact, the intuitive criterion was initially derived by Cho and kreps from (Kohlberg-Mertens-)strategic stability, which is a refinement in terms of the normal form.